# Android RadioButton circle button does not appear in API 20 and lower

Tags: java, android, user-interface, radio-button

I migrated from Eclipse to Android Studio recently.

I had a `RadioGroup` with `RadioButtons` in my app that were working with no problems on my Device (API 19). It seems that they appear if the API is higher than 21.

After upgrading to Android Studio, the button circles do not appear, although I have one of them checked.

Also, I tried changing the color, it still does not appear.

Also, tried using `ButtonTint` but that is not available until API 21

Thanks.

```
<RadioGroup
 android:id="@+id/menuGroup"      
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
 android:orientation="horizontal"

    >

 <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioAny"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Any" 
        android:checked="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
```

Comment: can you please post some of the code

Comment: layout for now just to see what u did

Comment: Just posted that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the style of the radio button.

Go to xml file where the button is declared then from the design part select the radio button and change it's style to `@android:style/Widget.Holo.CompoundButton.RadioButton`

Hope it works